# ion-button menuToggle disappears on dashboard page when i login and navigate to dashboard page, why ? - IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

When i open my app, the 1st page which appears is Login.html , after filling the form, it navigates to dashboard.html

**Problem:** When it goes to Dashboard.html , it does not shows menuToggle ion-button. Please help me resolve this issue

This is the code i am using for navigation in login.ts:

```
if(data[0].USR==1)
       {
         this.navCtrl.push(DashboardPage);

       }
```

my code in `dashboard.html`

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar hideBackButton="true">
    <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>dashboard..</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
  </ion-header>
```

> Please help me resolve this issue

**Please note:**
When i normally navigate from menu to dashboard page, it shows the menu toggle button.

Answer (score 3):

Would you like to try following html code for your `menuToggle`?

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar hideBackButton="true">

    <button ion-button menuToggle start>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>

    <ion-title>dashboard..</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Also note, if there isn't any `back` possibility from this dashboard view to your login view, I guess you would rather like to set it as `root` instead of `pushing it`. Therefore I would suggest to modify:

```
this.navCtrl.push(DashboardPage);
```

into

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(DashboardPage);
```

Comment: tried but still the same issue, let me clear cache and check again

Comment: Thanks @david-dal-busco that saved my day!

Comment: My pleasure Leonardo :)